# Bukkit countdown message sends message 4 times

Tags: bukkit

I just created a countdown method in Java, but i have a problem when the countdowner broadcasts the messages: 60(and down) seconds until the game starts!
The broadcast gets sent *4. Does anyone know any solution to this?

Here is my code:

```
Main plugin;

public StartCountdown(Main pl) {
    plugin = pl;
}

public static int timeUntilStart;

@Override
public void run() {
    for(Player p1 : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()){
            if(timeUntilStart == 0) {

                if(!Game.canStart()) {

                    plugin.restartCountdown();
                    ChatUtilities.broadcast(ChatColor.RED + "Not enough players to start. Countdown will");
                    ChatUtilities.broadcast(ChatColor.RED + "restart.");
                    p1.playSound(p1.getLocation(), Sound.ENDERDRAGON_WINGS, 5, 1);
                    return;
                }
                Game.start();
            }

             for(Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()){
                    p.setLevel(timeUntilStart);

            if(timeUntilStart < 11  || timeUntilStart == 60 || timeUntilStart == 30) {
                p.playSound(p.getLocation(), Sound.ORB_PICKUP, 5, 0);
                if(timeUntilStart == 1) {
                    p.playSound(p.getLocation(), Sound.ORB_PICKUP, 5, 1);
                }
                ChatUtilities.broadcast(String.valueOf(timeUntilStart)
                        + " §6Seconds until the game starts!");



             }







             }
}
    timeUntilStart -= 1;
```

}

```
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should use the Bukkit Scheduler and you have a because of the first for you send a broadcast for each Player that is online

Answer (score 0):

You are broadcasting for every player that is online. You need to move any code that you don't want to run for every player outside of the for loop.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    if (timeUntilStart == 0) {
        if (!Game.canStart()) {
            plugin.restartCountdown();
            ChatUtilities.broadcast(ChatColor.RED + "Not enough players to start. Countdown will");
            ChatUtilities.broadcast(ChatColor.RED + "restart.");
            for (Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) p.playSound(p.getLocation(), Sound.ENDERDRAGON_WINGS, 5, 1);
            return;
        }

        Game.start();
    }

    boolean broadcast;

    for (Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
        p.setLevel(timeUntilStart);

        if (timeUntilStart < 11  || timeUntilStart == 60 || timeUntilStart == 30) {
            p.playSound(p.getLocation(), Sound.ORB_PICKUP, 5, 0);
            if (timeUntilStart == 1) p.playSound(p.getLocation(), Sound.ORB_PICKUP, 5, 1);
            broadcast = true;
        }
    }

    if (broadcast) ChatUtilities.broadcast(String.valueOf(timeUntilStart) + " §6Seconds until the game starts!");

    timeUntilStart -= 1;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as Tanner Little said above

> You are broadcasting for every player that is online. You need to move any code that you don't want to run for every player outside of the for loop.

You need to make sure as well that you are cancelling the task. I would recommend using the inbuilt scheduler. You can access the scheduler in this way

```
private int countDownTimer
private int countDownTime
public void runCountDown() {
 countDownTimer = Bukkit.getScheduler.scheduleSyncDelayedTask(plugin, new runnable() {
  public void run {
   if (countDownTime <= 0) {
    //do your bradcasting here
    for (Player ingame : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
     //Do your player specific stuff here
    }
    Bukkit.getScheduler.cancelTask(countDownTimer);
   }
   if (countDownTime % 10 == 0) { //You can pick whaterver times u want this is just for an example
    //Do periodic broadcasting
   }
   countDownTime -= 1;
  }
 }, 0L, 20L); //This means that it would wait 0 ticks to start the countdown and do the task every 20 ticks ie) 1 second.
}
```

Hopefully this helps you.